# Why IE not showing my css box shadow effect

Tags: html, css

I have used box shadow effect via css3 which is well and good in other browsers while IE do not show those effect, can any one resolve this issue.

CSS3 SHADOW CODE

```
  #bshadow
{
/*  
-webkit-box-shadow: -9px -4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    -9px -4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         -9px -4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75); */

-webkit-box-shadow: -4px -5px 9px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    -4px -5px 9px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         -4px -5px 9px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);

-moz-border-radius-topleft: 44px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 44px;
 border-top-left-radius: 44px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 44px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 44px;
border-top-right-radius: 44px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;

}
```

Comment: [Duplicare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181699/box-shadow-in-ie7-and-ie8)

Comment: which version of IE???

Answer (score 2):

IE will use **filter:** property.

More info here: http://hedgerwow.appspot.com/demo/shadow
As shown in another stackoverflow question:

```css
/* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=2, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=2, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
```

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989391/how-do-i-convert-this-box-shadow-property-for-ie)